# How to change default file upload size limit in salesforce?

Tags: files, fileupload, system-admin, lightning-file-upload

In the documentation of lightning-file-upload it is stated that

> 'By default, you can upload up to 10 files simultaneously unless your
> Salesforce admin has changed that limit. The org limit for the number
> of files simultaneously uploaded is a maximum of 25 files and a
> minimum of 1 file. The maximum file size you can upload is 2 GB.'

I can not find the settings from where I can change the file size limit. I need to change the setting so that users cant upload a file for more than 5 mb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Permissions can be only changed by Salesforce Support Team. You need to open a Case to salesforce support team and give the details so they will validate and change it.